# Unable to process response after sending the request successfully using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm sending a cross domain request using jquery ajax. I can send the request successfully, but when I get response I get syntax error in console and XML processing error.

```
var xml_response="http://test.test.in:8080/RestAPI/ServiceRequestServlet?request=<xml><request><functiontype>2003</functiontype><groupzid>185</groupzid><moduleid>8</moduleid><servicetype>21</servicetype></request></xml>"

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dvContent").append("<ul></ul>");
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: xml_response,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(xml){

     alert("success");

  },
  error: function() {
    alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
  }
  });
});
```

I want to copy the response to a variable so that I can parse it

Comment: The server is returning XML formatted response and you are trying to parse it as json

Comment: Changing your `dataType` would fix the problem, however that brings up a crossdomain problem...

Comment: @Dola So what sould I do to this. It is a crossdomain problem

Comment: If you have control over the server that you are retrieving the data from, you can send the response with this header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yoursite.com`

Comment: @Dola Can you show be something I can do in fiddle

Comment: Do you control test.test.in?

Comment: @sharf No, I don't have control over it

Comment: Then Dola's suggestion won't work.

Comment: @sharf Please suggest me something

Comment: I do not have the experience to help with this. It's a problem I still have. The solution is `CORS`, not sure how to set it up though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing the xml data  through ajax instead of along with the url. And change the datatype to xml. Try changing the data parameter untill the request parameter is accessible in server($_GET['request']). Try without specifying the datatype.

```
 var xml_response="http://test.test.in:8080/RestAPI/ServiceRequestServlet"

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#dvContent").append("<ul></ul>");
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data:{request:"<xml><request><functiontype>2003</functiontype><groupzid>185</groupzid><moduleid>8</moduleid><servicetype>21</servicetype></request></xml>"},
        crossDomain: true,
        url: xml_response,
        success: function(xml){

         alert("success");

      },
      error: function() {
        alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
      }
      });
    });
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing : after property id
 

data:{request="<xml><request><functiontype>2003</functiontype><groupzid>1

Comment: Sorry use : instead of = in data: {request:...}.
Edited the code.

Comment: The "request" variable is accessible in server?

Comment: Code is edited. Try without specifying the datatype, so by default text it will return and in the js you can convert that to xml.

Comment: Still the same error...Can you try on the above fiddle and tell me